# Combine multiple results into a single row - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with a result set from a query

The results look something like this

```
ID  Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4  
ABC X       null    null    null  
ABC null    X       null    null  
ABC null    null    X       null  
ABC null    null    null    X
```

How can I combine this so that I end up with:

```
ID1 Col1 Col2  Col3 Col4  
ABC X    X     X    X
```

As my result set

Comment: What does your source table(s) look like? What is the query you are running to get your first result set? Why do you have four records with the same ID returned? Basically you have asked a question without enough information to be able to even start composing an answer.

Comment: Do `GROUP BY ID`, with `max()` (or `min()`) for the other columns.

Comment: I think you need [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17921/combine-column-from-multiple-rows-into-single-row)?

Comment: I did not have time to update this on Friday but I did find a solution to this using SSIS and the Pivot utility in there that does exactly what I want. Thanks to all those who looked at this